# Integral in mathematical expression of capacitor/resistor LTSpice

Tags: capacitor, resistors, simulation, ltspice

I know how to simulate a variable resistor in LTSpice. For example for a heating resistance the equation can be made by considering heating equation and can be expressed like R=(Ri-Ao*EXP(-time/To)) and further simulated,

But how to write a more complex mathematical expression like below-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the manual (`F1`) and look under `LTspice > Circuit Elements > B`, you'll see a table of functions, among which `idt()` (or `sdt()`) is the one you're looking for. For indefinite integration use simply `idt(x)`, where `x` can be the variable `time`, and for definite integration you can use that in association with `delay()` (or `absdelay()`): `idt(x-delay(x,1/T))`, for example. The <strike>`idt()` function</strike> `time` keyword has no meaning in `.AC` analysis. Also see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/254602/95619).

Answer (score 1):

One other way to integrate signals worth mentioning is to set the window time to the period that you want to integrate and then ctrl+click on the signal (can even be resistance) and it will give you and average and RMS value for the window time.

Comment: thanks, that also some useful info. :)