# How to integrate in LTSPICE when .step is used?

Tags: ltspice

I know that I can integrate any value in a LTSPICE using CTRL+LEFT_MOUSE. But now I used
*.step param Y 0 10 1* to vary my input. And my aim was to get the energy consumed for different input, thus I need to integrate the product of current and Vdd. That is showing some error. Is there anyway to do it without changing the *.step...*?

[image]

Comment: Plot settings -> select trace. Or something similar. I can check the exact name when I’m in front of my computer.

Comment: I generally do that , it will display the voltages and currents in the circuit. But when I use the .step param , no new node is named. Its like there is only one Vm(2) / Im(2) but when I plot it it will be multiple. I want to integrate it separately.  @winny

Comment: If I remember correctly you can show only a single trace with the syntax V(y) @ x, change x with the number of the trace you want to plot (e.g. 1,2,3...), and V(y) with the node or current.

Comment: V(y) @ x ? didnt get that   @FedeWar

Comment: Perhaps you can cheat around the problem with a .meas?

Comment: The issue is they dont have separate variable name. So like if it take average of Id(M2) I guess it will be average of current for 10 different inputs for one full cycle ? I guess Idk how to call them separately. I just gave Vdd*(Is(M2)+Is(M6)) , and solution for all different inputs are plotted. .meas need to be used by calling the variable name right?in this case is that possible?  @winny

Comment: If everything else fails, ngspice can for sure do it with a for-loop from console but it should be possible to create a loop in LTspice. Can you use @1, @2 and so on?

Comment: I dont know what this '@' thing is @winny

Comment: Can't LTSpice plot energy into a node?

Comment: Yes I can integrate the voltage and current in LTSPICE to get the energy at a node. But when I am using the above mentioned function , there is only one node name for all different inputs.

Comment: @winny that unfortunately does not work. It still gives the same error message.

Comment: You could also try adding your own [integrator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/254602/95619) and reading the values as voltages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly it is not possible with the graphical interface as it is.

What you can do to get around that limitation is use a `.meas` statement to do the integration for you.

I have drawn a very simple example:
[image: Small circuit]

With this measurement statement:

`.meas TRAN Energy INTEG V(n001)*I(R1) FROM 0 TO 1`

LTSpice will compute the integral of the expression `V(n001)*I(R1)` from 0 s to 1 s.

The results will be displayed in the SPICE Error Log (under view).

Which looks like this:
[image: Spice Error Log]

With a right click, you can plot the stepped data and get a result like this:
[image: Resulting plot of stepped data]

The X axis contains the actual step value (in my case resistance running from 1 to 101 ohm) and the Y axis is the measurement result (in this case the energy when integrating over 1 second from the start.

Read up on the `.meas` statement in the help, but the interface for it (place a `.meas` on the sheet and right click it) is quite comprehensive.

---

Side note as you didn't understand what @winny meant with using @ in the plot environment:

If you enter `V(n001)*I(R1) @ 1` instead of `V(n001)*I(R1)` into the expression to plot, it will only show you the plot of that specific step. This is nice if you have a step which is doing extraordinary things and you want to inspect it closer and get less confused.

It does not allow you to integrate with the CTRL + Left Click functionality though.